# Why does netlogo think this input is a true/false rather than a number?

Tags: netlogo

I have the code:

```
  ;; in one command block
    set J J = -1
    set A A = -1
  ;; in another command block
   every 6 [ set J J = -1]
```

When I press the button that corresponds to the second command block I get the runtime error "- expected input to be a number but got the TRUE/FALSE false instead". What is causing this and what should I do to remedy the problem. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

`set J J = -1` tests to see if `J` is equal to `-1` and then sets `J` to the result. You want:

```
  ;; in one command block
    set J -1
    set A -1
  ;; in another command block
   every 6 [ set J -1 ]
```